# Irobot create commands

Tags: ros, irobot-create, bash

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi!
I created a file called irobot.sh. I would like to open 3 different consoles to run 3 different commands.

#!/bin/bash

konsole --hold -e "roscore"

konsole --hold -e "rosrun irobot_create_2_1 driver.py"

konsole --hold -e "rosrun teleop_twist_keyboard teleop_twist_keyboard.py"

Roscore is working fine, but the other 2 commands are not working.
It opens the 3 consoles. But the two rosrun commands are no working, it shows this message:

Usage: rosrun PACKAGE EXECUTABLE [ARGS]
rosrun will locate PACKAGE and try to find
an executable named EXECUTABLE in the PACKAGE tree.
If it finds it, it will run it with ARGS.

If I open 3 consoles by myself, and run one command in every console, everything works well, but I want to use the script.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/45072/irobot-create-commands/) by [andreapatri](https://answers.ros.org/users/1713/andreapatri/) on ROS Answers with karma: 26 on 2012-10-03

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

[roslaunch](http://ros.org/wiki/roslaunch) probably does what you want. It is the preferred way for managing multiple nodes.

---

Originally posted by [Dan Lazewatsky](https://answers.ros.org/users/173/dan-lazewatsky/) with karma: 9115 on 2012-10-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1